# Different errors using the 'file-type' package in a browser (Angular)

Tags: javascript, browser, file-type

I have an Angular app and a component where I upload files. Now I want to check a real file's type using the  [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) library. It has a huge number of downloads and almost no issues, but I can't make it work. So, probably, I'm missing something basic but crucial.

I took the basic example of checking a file from BLOB:

```
const FileType = require('file-type/browser');
 
(async () => {
    const blob = new Blob(['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>'], {
        type: 'plain/text',
        endings: 'native'
    });
 
    console.log(await FileType.fromBlob(blob));
    //=> {ext: 'txt', mime: 'plain/text'}
})();
```

but it gives me an error:

> Error in C:/project/node_modules/readable-web-to-node-stream/lib/index.js
>
> Module not found: Error: can't resolve 'stream' in C:/project/node_modules/readable-web-to-node-stream/lib/

I've added a `stream` package (what is not a good solution, probably), and the error was changed to:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

After that, I decided that might be my current project is too complicated and I can give it a shot in a new small project, so I created one. Installed `file-type` and took the same example from their page (I only changed `const FileType = require('file-type/browser');` to `import {fromBlob} from 'file-type/browser'`);

But here another error appears:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

I added `(window as any)['global'] = window;` to the `polyfill.js`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined

I added the `buffer` package and `global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;` to the `polyfill.js`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Here I gave up. I definitely don't understand something and need some help. What I missed?

Wanted to add a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gl8au3), but it gives me another error:

> Import error, can't find file: ./common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the end I gave up using `.fromBlob` or `.fromStream` methods and `file-type/browser` part at all. What works:

polyfills.ts

```js
/*
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
(window as any).global = window;
// @ts-ignore
// tslint:disable no-var-requires
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
```

component.ts

```js
import { fromBuffer, FileTypeResult } from 'file-type/core';

async getTrueFileType(file: File): Promise<FileTypeResult | undefined> {
  return file.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => fromBuffer(buffer));
}

async validateFile(file) {
  const ext = await this.getTrueFileType(file);
  console.log(ext); // {ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png'}
}
```

For more details you can read the [issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/issues/354)